# How to refer to external files i.e. images on a Win / macOS Qt project?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, qt5

We can load an image to i.e. `QPixmap` by doing

```
QPixmap("image.png");
```

Then we put `image.png` at root project folder and it works, on Windows. I mean, the executable will find the image.

We can easily compile the Qt project on macOS too. But macOS executable is different, it's kind of a folder and the actual exectuble is down there, actually in a diferent path relative to the image. So image won't be found at runtime.

One approch to deal with that issue is to

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
// Code that will only be compiled under MAC OS X
#endif
```

Then we repeat this everywhere in the codebase and probem gonna be solved. Is there any alternative single shot solution? So that it's not necessary to change all codebase, perhaps trap the macOS executable to think it is in another path?

Reference: https://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/07/26/how-to-configure-a-single-qt-project-for-different-operating-systems/

Comment: May it be feasible for you to use Qt resource system? If you put your files in a Qt resource, you can just load like QPixmap(":/image.png") and the file is bundled as needed for all platforms. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html if you are unaware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two ways to achieve it.

The first one is to get the executable folder location (using the `main` parameters) and use paths relative to this one.
I already have provided an example here: [How can i access resources in c++ without setting the full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626409/how-can-i-access-resources-in-c-without-setting-the-full-path/57627566#57627566).

The second one is to use the [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).
It allows you to embed your resources into your executable.

**PS (edit):** I answered a bit too late (too much time to write :) ). The already given answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to solve this issue:

1) Use absolute file paths to your image files. This may be different depending on OS you run the application, like:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
    QPixmap(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/some_directory/" + "image.png");
#else
    QPixmap("image.png");
#endif
```

2) [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), i.e. embed the image into the executable.