# ifstream short path doesn't work in c++, macos

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

There are 3 lines from my draft. It runs perfectly, although it may have some weaknesses.

My problem is that when I'm compiling it in my Mac OS machine, `std::ifstream` doesn't work with short paths, only with full paths.
File "names.txt" is in the same folder with the program and the file "usednames.txt".
Short paths work in Linux and Windows, but it is not in Mac OS.
The same problem with `fopen()` in C. It doesn't work with "names.txt", "./names.txt", and also I can output an error, if I'll try this.

Is it a way to solve it, or it is in understanding Mac OS, or I'm doing something wrong?

```c++
std::ifstream names("/Users/*username*/Documents/blabla/names.txt");
std::ifstream usednamesRead("/Users/*username*/Documents/blabla/usednames.txt");
usednames.open("/Users/*username*/Documents/blabla/usednames.txt", std::ios::app);
```

Comment: My guess is that the programs *working directory* when running isn't what you expect it to be, making all relative paths (which are relative from the working directory) invalid. How do you build your program? And more importantly, how do you *run* your program?

Comment: You can check the working directory from inside the program with the `getcwd` system call. It will be different from "/Users/*username*/Documents/blabla".

Comment: Thank you, why I didn't think about it... I compiled it in atom with gcc compiler, it seems, that it makes a.out in the another direction. I tryed it in terminal with short path and it worked.

Comment: You may be interested by [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626409/how-can-i-access-resources-in-c-without-setting-the-full-path/57627566#57627566) that shows a way to safely use relative paths from the executable location.